# Reading file in groups of 4 lines

Tags: python, text, sum, line

I have a big file filed with numbers. About 15 lines of several numbers.
I'm trying to read it in groups of 4 lines and printing the result for every 4 lines. I have this code for now which prints too many results I only want the final ones. But it also stops at the first four lines. Is there a way to make it continue until the end?

looking for this type of output:

```
Lines 1-4 => 125
Lines 5-8 => 2073
Lines 9-12 => 559
Lines 13-16 => 471
```

thank you in advance for any help.

```py
for i in range(4):
line = ""
somme2 = 0
for i in range(4):
    line = fichNbr.readline().split()
    for n in line:
        somme2 += int(n)

print(somme2)
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and include an expected input and output? It may be easier to find an answer to your question!

Comment: And more generally, a duplicate of [How do I split a list into equally-sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks).